# How to Paint Geometry?

Tags: hair

I would like to know how i can paint geometry in blender as shown in this maya tutorial

https://youtu.be/6Wi4-fdeYyM?t=703

I asked on blenderartists about 2 years ago but I didnt have any detailed reply for it. So i try ask here and see if someone here can guide me through the process of painting geometry in Blender

Comment: You might want to look into Andreas Esau's [Asset Sketcher](https://www.blendermarket.com/products/asset-sketcher-v10)... It's not free, though.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but 30$ is a little expensive when i only want to know this one thing :)

Comment: In Blender, you can use particles and vertex groups to (weight) paint the hair with the wanted shape.

Comment: Yes. I know, But thats not same as shown in the video. if i weight paint i need to go out of weight paint to see the hair but in the video the hair appear as he paint on the model